# how to rounded line through in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField. This TextField has one LineThrough.

```
TextField(
              controller: controller.textEditingController
                ..text = controller.textEditingController.text,
              textAlign: controller.align.value,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: null,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,

                decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                decorationThickness: 20,

                decorationColor: Colors.white
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: LocaleKeys.type_here.tr,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: controller.selectedColorShape.value.textColor
                      .withOpacity(0.5),
                  shadows: const [],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

i want rounded Line through like this picture.how do i do?

The photo below is an application with a flutter.
[image]

I did not find this feature anywhere